# Echo custom attribute if another custom attribute is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, product-attribute

I show product reviews based on SKU. what I want is to use the sku of an attribute but if that attribute is empty use another.

For Example:

```
echo $_product->getwildcardSKU_attribute
if( wildcardSKU_attribute = empty ){
echo $_product->getSKU_attribute
}
```

I know my code makes no sense but it is just an example.

This is the code I need to use it in.

```
<?php echo $this->__('<img src="https://www.someURL.com=' . $_product->getwildcardsku() . '" alt="">') ?>
```

Comment: what your attribute code?

Comment: @arunendra is right. follow that code.

Comment: a code like that just can't work function are getWildCardSku() or getData('wild_card_sku') assuming that wild_card_sku is the name of the attribute. you have an affectation instead of comparison in your if, empty() does what you need and a $ is missing for the variable. Moreover, the helper class "catalog/output" as a function productAttribute that should be used to prepare the attribute for front display.

Comment: I cannot seem to use the code as the page breaks when i try and echo inside the code Im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

Exp: Suppose your attribute code is :  `wild_cards_sku`

then you can get it using below code:

```
<?php
 $wildCardSku = $_product->getWildCardsSku();
if(empty($wildCardSku)){
    $wildCardSku = $_product->getSku();
 } 
  echo $this->__('<img src="https://www.someURL.com=' . $wildCardSku. '" alt="">');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but how could it work in my code. Please see my updated question

Comment: I have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
echo empty($_product->getWildcardskuSku) ? $_product->getSku() : $_product->getWildcardskuSku();
```

Please note that : `$_product->getwildcardSKU_attribute()` is not correctly written. Please correct this to `$_product->getWildcardskuSku()`